# Alinear dos módulos en Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Tengo 2 módulos de prestashop, módulo de búsqueda y módulo `user info`, ambos se encuentran en lineas diferentes. ¿Cómo puedo colocar un módulo al lado del otro? es decir, en la misma línea.

Así tengo mis módulos:

[image: Así tengo mis módulos]

Así lo deseo:

[image: Asi lo deseo]

Comment: ¿Qué versión de prestashop -exacta- estás usando? ¿Puedes pasarnos el link de tus módulos o una manera de encontrarlos?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con prestashop 1.6.1.4
modulos:
-Bloque de información de usuario
-Bloque de información de usuario

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a añadir en la capa principal de cada uno de los dos módulos la clase pull-right de bootstrap (o bien un float: right en css) de forma que ambos floten por la derecha. Si esto te descuadra otras capas o se te solapan, agrupa ambos módulos en otra capa para evitar problemas con el float.

```
    <div class="pull-right">
            Contenido de módulo de búsqueda
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
           Contenido de módulo de usuario
    </div>
```